# ffmpeg - Streaming rtsp data to local mp4 file

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming

How can I save live streaming data from a local camera transported by rtsp to my local memory in a `.mp4` format.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and tried using `ffmpeg` 3.3 but nothing seemed to work properly.

The goal will be to provide live feed by mp4 by html5 and perform some modification on mp4 data.

Can anyone suggest how to make `ffmpeg` work or any other way?

Comment: In memory MP4 is sort of contradictory. MP4 is primarially an on disk format, like rtmp is an on wire format.